# Formatting C# - removing blank lines in Visual Studio WITHOUT regex

Tags: formatting, visual-studio

Coming from an Eclipse background where I did lots of Java and AS3 coding its frustrating trying to format my code and classes in Visual Studio.

In Eclipse there was-is a plugin, PrettyPrint which allowed powerful 1 click formatting, removing of blank lines, indenting, etc.

Is there anything similar for formatting C# code with VisualStudio ?

Comment: configuring the code formatting options for your preferences, and then hitting Ctrl + Alt + D (IIRC) will format it how you specify, there are several options for blanks. beware however that gratuitous formatting changes can make version control comparisions and merges more difficult. Its best to have one standard for the team.

Comment: Thanks Frank. If you make this an answer instead of comment will accept.

Comment: @Frank Thomas It does not have an option to remove double blank lines